# How to disable new document at Microsoft Word 2007 startup?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Goal: open Word and open one or more of the recently used documents.

Current steps:

1. Start Word
2. Close new document
3. Open recently used document(s)

Is there a way to skip the following step?

- Close new document

The perfect solution would not involve macros but use an option or the command line instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a document to open, then a new document is not created.

E.g. when you double click on a Word document (or any document associated with Word) it opens that document, not a new blank document.

Command line: *path-to-word path-to-document*

Also the `/n` command line switch will prevent opening a new document.

Comment: Thanks for this useful hint, but since I want to access the recently used docs, this is not relevant for this scenario.

Comment: @Bernard: Notice the last paragraph: you can modify the shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly then opening a document while an empty, non-modified document is open, will automatically close that non-modified default document? Simply skip step 2 then.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to close the "New Document". After opening Word, click on the ribbon, then click on the used document you want to open. The new document will automatically be closed and your document will be opened.